# Element.hover not working on Raphael Javascript library

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a fully functioning 'scrapbook' type thing going on using the raphael javascript library. because the transformed images overlap I had a hover effect going on that brought the image to the front and added a glow, and then removed the glow on leave. A click event then brought the images up in colorbox. All this worked absolutely fine except in IE 7 and 8 - the hover worked and brought the image forward but the glow wasn't removed and the following click event didn't work at all as a result. Removing the entrie hover event section has fixed the click event but I'd really like to implement this hover effect.

Here's the script block:

```
paper.forEach(function (el) {
    el.hover(
        function() {
            el.toFront();
            el.g = this.glow();
        },
        function() {
            el.g.remove();
        }
    );

    // el.click block goes here and breaks if the el.hover block above is uncommented in IE 7 and 8
});
```

The rest of the code is all dynamically generated from a database and pretty tricky to get onto here AND make sense to everyone. Just wanted to know if there's anything wrong with the above? I've get everything else working fine but this is my first outing with Raphael so I'm not very confident!

Thanks.